# Для чего нужен eval в php?

Tags: php, eval

Не могу понять для чего нужен eval в php? В каких случаях часто используется?
Нужен небольшой пример с объяснением.

Comment: [офф документацию](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.eval.php) не читали?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

eval('text') лично я использовал как то для транслейтов. то есть в транслейте нужно вставить параметр, например: 
Файл с переменными языка:

```
...
$lang->Hello = 'Привет $user. Во время твоего отсутствии тебя проведали $visitors друзей'
...
```

Использования:

```
...
$user = 'Вася';
$visitors = 15;
...
eval ("\$pr_text = \"$lang->getText('Hello')\";");
print $str;
...
```

Answer (score 3):

Он просто выполняет код который вы передаете аргументом в виде строки, например как описано на http://php.net/

```
$string = 'cup';
$name = 'coffee';
$str = 'This is a $string with my $name in it.';
echo $str. "\n";
eval("\$str = \"$str\";");
echo $str. "\n";
```

результат будет

```
This is a $string with my $name in it.
This is a cup with my coffee in it.
```

при eval подставятся переменные, так-же можно можно передавать вызовы функций и еще чего либо.

Но использование этого не рекомендуеться. Трижды подумайте перед использованием этих вещей...

Comment: ха-ха-ха   копипаст с первой ссылки  выдачи гугла?))

Comment: да, именно так, ссылка на источник приложена, в чем проблема? мне кажется в общедоступных источниках все достаточно четко расписано.

Comment: я думаю, что автор вопроса это видел, но не понял где это можно применить в реальной практике, ему нужны реальные примеры а не теорию))) перед тем как писать вопросы все гуглят)))

Comment: знаю на практике далеко не все. А реально правильного применения этой функции на практике не встречал. У новичков видел при проведении ревью, но с целесообразным применением пока все-таки не стыкался.